# The interface cannot be used as type argument. Static member does not have a most specific implementation in the interface

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following implementation which uses .NET 7's static abstract member functionality:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    public static abstract string Bar { get; }
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public static string Bar => "Bar"
}
```

Now, whenever I use the interface as a type parameter to a generic class, I get an error. For example, if my Program.cs looks like this:

```
List<IFoo> fooList = new List<Foo>();
```

I get the following error:

> error CS8920: The interface 'IFoo' cannot be used as type argument.
> Static member 'IFoo.Bar' does not have a most specific implementation
> in the interface.

I guess that, for whatever reason, this is a C# restriction. I could be wrong, though, so now I'm asking: is there any way to solve this case or at least get around this restriction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I guess that, for whatever reason, this is a C# restriction.

Yes, the restriction is explained in the [specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-11.0/static-abstracts-in-interfaces#interfaces-as-type-arguments) and the reason is type safety. Example from the linked [github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/5955):

```cs
interface I
{
    static abstract string P { get; }
}
class C<T> where T : I
{
    void M() { Console.WriteLine(T.P); }
}
new C<I>().M(); // Error
```

You can "fix" it by using the `static virtual` method:

```cs
public interface IFoo
{
    public static virtual string Bar => throw new Exception();
}
```

Problem here is that now implementors do not need to implement the method:

```cs
public class Foo1 : IFoo // valid now
{
}
```

Another approach is to use marker interface (though it can be considered an [antipattern](https://blog.ndepend.com/marker-interface-isnt-pattern-good-idea/)):

```
public interface IAmActuallyFoo
{
    
}
public interface IFoo : IAmActuallyFoo
{
    public static abstract string Bar { get; }
}

var fooList = new List<IAmActuallyFoo>();
```

P.S.

Note that `List<IFoo> fooList = new List<Foo>();` is invalid anyway because variance is not supported by classes (see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5582491/2501279) and/or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/246101/2501279) answer).

Comment: Nice! Even though it could break things, it's a bit weird to me that you can't use the interface as a type parameter, since that is a very common scenario. The use case I currently have for this is polymorphic deserialization of json. That basically requires that the type argument is the interface. Good thing that the virtual method exists, but it's a shame that you can't enforce the implementation. Anyways, thanks!

Comment: @AndreasForslöw was glad to help! If you really want - you can enforce the implementation by writing custom analyzer =)

Comment: Right... I didn't even think about the invalid syntax. Anyways, I hope it's clear to everyone that the question is just a very simple mockup to demonstrate the issue. And yeah, a custom analyzer is definitely a smart option.. Just a very ambitious one :)